# SQL Constraints OR Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints

How can I have an SQL constraint with an OR condition:

```
USE [dbname]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_table] CHECK  (([field1] like ('[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]' OR '[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]') AND [field1] IS NOT NULL))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_table]
GO


field1 = varchar[10]
```

Goal is to check for size 2 or size 3 with allowed characters

Problem is 'OR' throws error of unknown

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please include the appropriate tag. What is the error that gets provided?

Comment: `... OR [field1] like '[0-9a-zA-Z]' ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
USE [dbname]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_table] CHECK  ([field1] like '[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]' OR [field1] like '[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]') AND [field1] IS NOT NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_table]
GO
```

You have problem here

```
([field1] like ('[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]' OR '[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]')
```

Means you wrote something like this `(field1 like 'x' or 'y')` which is not correct syntax. You need to write like `(field1 like 'x' or field1 like 'y')`

Comment: Also it is good practice to always put OR inside brackets (field1 like 'x' or field1 like 'y')

Comment: Definitely. In fact he did that too.

Comment: @e2fx - It's great that your problem is sorted out. Don't forget [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL` check should be handled with a simple `NOT NULL` constraint.  If you do include it, it should be phrased correctly and not just tacked onto the second condition:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_table]
        CHECK  ( ([field1] like '[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]' OR
                  [field1] like '[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]'
                 ) AND
                 field1 is not null
               );
```

The `LIKE` guarantees that the value is not `NULL`; an additional check is not necessary.

If you have chains of these, you can also write this as:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_table]
        CHECK  ([field1] not like ('%[^0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]%' AND
                LEN(field1) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 AND
                field1 is not null
               );
```

The first condition says that everything is alphanumeric (by using double negatives).  The second specifies how long the column is.  For two lengths, the two methods are about the same.  If you allowed fields with 2-6 characters, this would be simpler.

Comment: The `NOT NULL` *is* necessary. Constraints reject `false` and accept `true` and `unknown` - though it should be a `NOT NULL` rather than left to the check constraint.